# How to insert pages document to another pages document?

Tags: macos, pages, copy-paste

I am using Mavericks, and Pages 5.1. I have created two .pages documents. Now, all I want is to attach one .pages document to another. In windows I could simply drag and drop or copy and paste both would have worked. But in Mac when I  :

1. Press command + c then command + v, it pastes the files name instead of the file.
2. Drag and Drop doesn't work at all.
3. Menu > Insert > Choose . Here all files looks disabled. I can attach a .mov file but no other files, be it .pages , .numbers , .csv  etc.

How do we insert one pages document to another pages document?

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder paste the two files into it. Now hyperlink the two files by opening the document (whichever you are trying to add a link in) then click inspector after you have the text you want to hyperlink, for the hyperlink URL, try the following.

```
    Insert other pages document name here.pages
```

Now close the document and save all changes. 
Right click the folder and compress it, then email the compressed folder to the person you are trying to send this to.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same version of Pages and Mavericks but I cannot duplicate your items 1 and 2. I was able to move an entire document or just one page of it by selecting the text and using copy and paste as well as drag and drop of the selected text. Formatting is also preserved.

Comment: Thanks for reply @wendy. But I dont have to copy paste the content of another document. I have to insert/attach the document to another document. So that when I send my document to other. They can click and open the attach document inside it.